# Isomorphic objects have the same dimension (pivotal categories)

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I want to prove that if two objects $X,Y$ in a pivotal category $\mathcal{C}$ (is that enough? Or do we need something more?) are isomorphic, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{dim}(X) = \mathrm{Tr}^{L}(\mathrm{id}_{X}) =  \mathrm{Tr}^{L}(\mathrm{id}_{Y}) = \mathrm{dim}(Y),$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}^{L}$ is the left quantum trace (see Tensor Categories-EGNO Ch 4.7). I want to show that the following diagram, corresponding to the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$, commutes:

[image]

Here $f\colon X \to Y$ is an isomorphism and $f^{\ast-1}$ is the dual morphism of $f^{-1}$.

I was able to show that the inner square commutes, but I am having trouble showing that the outer triangles commute. I tried taking the explicit form of $(f^{-1})^{\ast}$ but I don't get that the composition with $\mathrm{coev}_{X}$ should be $\mathrm{coev}_{Y}$. I would appreciate a hint for this last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to know about string diagrams here is a simple diagrammatic proof for the left triangle:
[image]

And below is that same proof translated word for word into familiar (perhaps too verbose) equations. The right triangle is done in a similar way. Note the use of the definition of the dual of $f^{-1}$ and the rigidity axiom

$$ (f \otimes f^{*-1}) \text{coev}_X $$
$$ =(f \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes f^{*-1}) \text{coev}_X $$
$$ = (f \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes \text{ev}_X \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes 1_{X^*} \otimes f^{-1} \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes 1_{X^*} \otimes \text{coev}_Y)\text{coev}_X $$
$$ = (f \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes \text{ev}_X \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes 1_{X^*} \otimes f^{-1} \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (\text{coev}_X \otimes 1_Y \otimes 1_{Y^*}) \text{coev}_Y $$
$$ = (f \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (1_X \otimes \text{ev}_X \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (\text{coev}_X \otimes 1_X \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (f^{-1} \otimes 1_{Y^*}) \text{coev}_Y $$
$$= (f \otimes 1_{Y^*}) (f^{-1} \otimes 1_{Y^*}) \text{coev}_Y $$
$$ = \text{coev}_Y $$

You should justify each step to yourself, but the steps that might not be obvious in these equations just use functoriality of the monoidal product. This is where string diagrams really help make sense of things, functoriality here basically amounts to moving strings up and down, which is easy to see graphically.